# Java array references are null after being set

Tags: java

```
public abstract class Class1 {
    protected static Object object1 = null;
    protected static Object object2 = null;

    public static Object[] objects = { object1, object2 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Class2();

        for (Object o : objects) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }
}

public class Class2 extends Class1 {
    public Class2() {
        Class1.object1 = new String("String 1");
        Class1.object2 = new String("String 2");
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
null
null
```

Why?

When I create a new instance of `Class2`, the constructor for that class initializes `object1` and `object2`.

`objects`, as far as I know, contains references to these Objects. So after they're initialized, I expected anything but null.

Could someone explain? Thanks.

Comment: `int x = 3; int y = x; x = 5;` y is still 3.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis *Slightly* disagree with duplicate as the link is about function parameters, and even though it's the same idea, it would be difficult for the OP here to make that jump.

Comment: If you didn't catch it earlier, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`object` doesn't contain references to these `object1` and `object2`, but contains **copied references** to these objects.

If you do:

```
public static Object[] objects;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Class2();

    objects = { object1, object2 };
    for (Object o : objects) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

i.e. initialize `object` after you initialize `object1` and `object2` you will have copies in the array that are not empty.

Answer (score 3):

When instanciating your object first this

```
protected static Object object1 = null;
protected static Object object2 = null;
```

sets `object1` and `object2` to be `null`-references.

Then this

```
objects = { object1, object2 };
```

copies the references that `object1` and `object2` contain at that time to `objects[0]` and `objects[1]`.

Then here

```
    Class1.object1 = new String("String 1");
    Class1.object2 = new String("String 2");
```

you create new `String`-references that get stored in `object1` and `object2` - but the copies in `objects[0]` and `objects[1]` are unaffected.